# Reducing a large array of objects to a simple object with 8 properties

Tags: javascript

I'm reducing a large array of objects to a simple object with 8 properties. I'm currently using `Array.prototype.reduce` to loop through the array of objects to create a new object. In order to assign a correct key to the value in the array I'm using a `switch` statement. **My code currently works**, but I'm looking to refine it. I have no control over the API and how it returns its response.

The array of objects that are returned look like this:

```
[
  {
    field_id:89107336,
    values : [{ value:"Star Warz"}]
  },
  {
    field_id:89107337,
    values : [{ date:"December 24, 2015"}]
  },
  {
    field_id:89107415,
    values : [
               {
                 value: { item_id:1234123}
               },
               {
                 value: { item_id:4746576}
               }
  },
  {
    field_id:89107340,
    values : [{ value:"5.00"}]
  },
  {
    field_id:89107344,
    values : [{ value:"This is description"}]
  },
  {
    field_id:89107348,
    values : [
               { 
                 value:{file_id:234234}
               }
             ]
  }
]
```

The object values come back random at times, so the only way for me to tell the difference between the title, the date, description, etc. Is for me to run the response through a `switch` statement based upon `field_id`. So I created an object like so:

```
var eventFieldIds = {
        title: 89107336,
        date: 89107337,
        attendees: 89107415,
        price: 89107340,
        desc: 89107344,
        img: 89107348
    };
```

Then I use a switch statement to reduce the array objects  like this:

```
var newEvent = arrayObjects.reduce(function(p, c) {
    switch (c.field_id) {
        case eventFieldIds.title:
            {
                p.name = c.values[0].value;
                break;
            }
        case eventFieldIds.date:
            {
                p.date = new Date(c.values[0].start_date);
                break;
            }
        case eventFieldIds.attendees:
            {
                //this is an array of values
                var tempArray = c.values.map(function(v) {
                    return value.value.item_id;
                });
                p.attendees = JSON.stringify(tempArray);
                break;
            }
        case eventFieldIds.price:
            {
                p.price = c.values[0].value;
                break;
            }
        case eventFieldIds.desc:
            {
                p.description = c.values[0].value;
                break;
            }
        case eventFieldIds.img:
            {
                p.img = {
                    file_id: c.values[0].value.file_id
                };
                break;
            }
    }

    return p;
}, {});
```

How can I refine this? Can I cut out the `switch` statement? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd flip the field-id-to-name lookup around, and give it some more detail; e.g.

```
function defaultConverter(values) {
  return values[0].value;
} 

var mappings = {
  "89107336": { name: "title", converter: defaultConverter },
  "89107340": { name: "price", converter: defaultConverter },
  "89107344": { name: "desc", converter: defaultConverter },
  "89107337": {
    name: "date",
    converter: function (values) {
      return new Date(values[0].start_date);
    }
  },
  "89107348": {
    name: "img",
    converter: function (values) {
      return values[0].value.file_id;
    }
  },
  "89107415": {
    name: "attendees",
    converter: function (values) {
      var items = values.map(function (v) { return v.value.item_id });
      return JSON.stringify(items);
    }
  }
};
```

This way you declare how each piece of data should be treated, and you can easily extend it.

Your `reduce` can then become this:

```
var output = data.reduce(function (output, obj) {
  var mapper = mappings[obj.field_id];
  if(map) {
    output[map.name] = map.converter(obj.values)
  }
  return output;
}, {});
```

---

You can make the mapping declaration a little less repetitive like so:

```
function Mapping(name, converter) {
  this.name = name;
  this.converter = converter || function (values) { return values[0].value };
}

var mappings = {
  "89107336": new Mapping("title"),
  "89107340": new Mapping("price"),
  "89107344": new Mapping("desc"),
  "89107337": new Mapping("date", function (values) {
    return new Date(values[0].start_date);
  }),
  "89107348": new Mapping("img", function (values) {
    return values[0].value.file_id;
  }),
  "89107415": new Mapping("attendees", function (values) {
    var items = values.map(function (v) { return v.value.item_id });
    return JSON.stringify(items);
  })
};
```

and still use the same `reduce` function.

Comment: This looks great! Flambino, I've read alot of books recently to try to become better at Javascript like, "Effective Javascript", "Javascript Patterns", "Javascript the Good Parts". I can understand everything you did, but yet I haven't become fluent enough indesign. What would you recommend for me to study or do now?

Comment: @inspired That's a tough one. I can't think of any books; I'd recommend just practicing. Find some code exercises, do some hobby projects, etc.. Anything to hone your skills, really. But also: Look at other people's code. I learned a lot this way. You can also review things on this site! Design-wise, I personally like to go fairly top-down. For each part of a problem I think "I want to be able to just write [some imaginary, ideal piece of code], so how do I get to that point?". Along the way, look for ways to encapsulate things, avoid repetition, add flexibility, decouple things, etc..

Comment: Flambino, Thanks alot for your help! I've read alot JS books, in the interest of become as proficient as possible. I love the language

Comment: Flambino, would it be beneficial to add the converter method to the `Mappings.prototype`, so that it won't be attached to each instance? Then I could attach`defaultConverter`, `dateConverter`,`attendeeConverter` methods? Would that be useful?

Comment: @inspired I wouldn't bother. A mapping instance should be generic. Giving it a bunch of specialized prototype methods would defeat that. It should not know or care about attendees or dates. A mapping instance would just end up with a lot of clutter, and you'd have to rework the prototype to add more conversions. In the code above, writing `new Mapping(a, b)` is really just another way of writing `{ name: a, converter: b }` with just a touch more formality. But if you find something that'd be useful for _all_ mappings, then yes: Prototype method.